# OAuth token expired and refresh token is not set

Tags: go, oauth, token, refresh-token

I am working on some HTTP APIs for which I need OAuth. I am using [OAuth Package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2). It works at first but after some time I start getting error

> Token expired and refresh token is not set.

Here is my config

```
userCfg := &oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     a.ClientID,
    ClientSecret: a.ClientSecret,
    Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
        TokenURL:  a.ProviderURL,
        AuthStyle: oauth2.AuthStyleInParams, // basic auth is not supported by Ping
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem on my own, I put a check that if a received token expires error then instead of sending the error back, I request the token again else I return the error.

```
refreshErr := "oauth2: token expired and refresh token is not set"

// use token source to retrieve the configured token or a new token
token, err := a.tokenSource.Token()
if err != nil && strings.Contains(err.Error(), refreshErr) {
    // update the token source
    a.tokenSource, err = a.getUserToken()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // get the new token
    token, err = a.tokenSource.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
} else if err != nil { // some other error than refresh token error
    return "", err
}
```

You can define the `refreshErr` as a constant in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I see somewhere that adding `Scopes: []string{"offline_access"}` can resolve this issue. It takes a lot of time for me to actually add something and then deploy and test. So i just want to know if it's the correct answer or do I need to do something else.